# Error getting after used hooks in behave framework python (before_scenario and after_scenario)

Tags: python, hook, python-behave

[image]I used `environment.py` in my code. I used hooks `before_scenario` and `after_scenario`.
After the first test run. Got an error immediately. In this code am i doing something wrong?

```
from common.selen_base import Browser


def before_scenario(context,scenario):
    context.browser = Browser()


def after_scenario(context,scenario):
    context.browser.close_all()
```

[Error after run the Feature]

```
class WebDriverManager(object):

    __driver = None

    @classmethod
    def get_web_driver(cls):
        if cls.__driver is None:
            cls.__driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/usr/local/bin/chromedriver")
            cls.__driver.maximize_window()

        return cls.__driver


class Browser(object):
    __driver = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.__driver = WebDriverManager.get_web_driver()
        self.wait = WebDriverWait(self.__driver, 10)
```

Comment: pls. post what is the error

Comment: @Krzysztof I added the error screenshot . raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
      urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=62303): Max retries exceeded with url: /session/bcc05aa2f62bae44ec247329b7fed50e/url (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x106032390>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused'))

Answer (score 0):

You can add this at top of `environment.py` file:

```py
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)
```

This should resolve the issue

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).